# Rails 4 disable subdomain on link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

I would like disable subdomain on link_to but it's not working.

Her's my route.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints subdomain: false do
    root to: 'welcome#index'
    # USERS
    devise_for :users
    resource :user, only: [:edit] do
        collection do
            patch 'update_password'
        end
    end
    resource :users do
        collection do
            match 'show/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :user_show, via: 'get'
            match '' => 'users#index', :as => :user_index, via: 'get'
        end
    end

  end
```

constraints subdomain: /.+/ do
    namespace :manager do
      scope shallow_prefix: "sekret" do
        resources :articles
        root 'manager#index'
      end
    end
  end

end

When i'm on "test.local.dev/manager" and create a link_to :

```
=link_to article.user.username, user_show_users_path(article.user)
```

But normally this returning "local.dev/users/show/:id but this is returning "test.local.dev/users/show/:id"

I would like remove the subdomain "test".

When can i make that ?

Comment: You need to use `path_helper_url` rather than `path_helper_path` -- paths are relative; subdomains need an absolute url. In your case, you'd use `user_show_users_url(article.user, subdomain: "test")`, although the subdomain declaration may be incorrect. Looks like your routes need fixing too, if you don't get an answer I'll write one for you, we use subdomains extensively

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for your answer. if i add user_show_users_url(article.user, subdomain: false) it's working fine !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code:

```
<%= link_to article.user.username, user_show_users_url(article.user,:subdomain=>false)%>
```

Comment: Yes, i have already tried this solution but she is not working.

Comment: I have updated the code, try `url` instead of `path`

Comment: Would you like me to recommend a better way for your routes or no?